# Switch text with str_replace and arrays

Tags: php, string

Here's something interesting I've just found out regarding str_replace().
In my function I need to make two mysql queries which are the same with the slight change on sorting the result. As an argument I get string containing an order clause, for example 'surname ASC' but it could be 'surname DESC' as well. Now I wanted to easily switch to the reverse sorting using str_replace and I thought this should do the trick:

```
str_replace(array('ASC', 'DESC'), array('DESC', 'ASC'), $subject)
```

In my mind it should change all occurences of ASC with DESC and all occurences of DESC with ASC. Since the string contains only one of the two I should get reversed order clause.
However this is not the case. The output of the above code is the same string.

I did some testing and it tourned out that these calls do what you want them to do:

```
str_replace('ASC', 'DESC', $subject)
str_replace(array('ASC'), array('DESC'), $subject)
```

In my opinion this is weird because

```
array('ASC', 'DESC') != array('DESC', 'ASC')
```

Why then PHP would consider this as equal? Is there any other way to make this kind of replacement easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this scenario, you can use [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) like so:

```
strtr($subject, array('ASC' => 'DESC', 'DESC' => 'ASC'));
```

This will work because

> If given two arguments, the second should be an array in the form
>   `array('from' => 'to', ...)`. The return value is a string where all the
>   occurrences of the array keys have been replaced by the corresponding
>   values. The longest keys will be tried first. Once a substring has
>   been replaced, its new value will not be searched again.

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/S6SZz)**.

With `str_replace` what happens, as you have already found out, is that first `ASC` is replaced with `DESC` and then `DESC` is replaced back to `ASC`, for a grand total of nothing done.

Answer (score 3):

PHP "renders" the first parameter first, changing all of the occurrences the way you want to (all `ASC` set to `DESC`).

But then you pass the second parameter saying to do the opposite, so all `DESC`s are set to `ASC`, basically nulling out your first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I fact I just guess: The replacements are consecutive. This means, it first replaces `ASC` with `DESC` and then `DESC` with `ASC`, which will result into the same string again.

Update: It seems, I'm right

```
php > $a = 'I am a string';
php > var_dump(str_replace(array('am', 'is'), array('is', 'k'), $a));
string(12) "I k a string"
```

First it replace `am` with `is` (the first entry) and then `is` with `k`